# How to get preceding line to filter in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to obtain the preceding row before applying the filter, preferably using dplyr, as I need to perform the operation by group for a large dataset.

As an example, let's assume I have this object:

```
structure(list(ano = c(2013, 2015, 2017, 2017, 2025, 2050, 2060
), difference = c(NA, 2, 2, 0, 8, 25, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I would like to apply a filter where, if the value of the difference is greater than or equal to 2, it captures the immediately preceding row, resulting in something like:

```
structure(list(ano = c(2013, 2015, 2017, 2025, 2050), difference = c("NA", 
"2", "0", "8", "25")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead` to reference the next row

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(lead(difference) >= 2)
#>    ano difference
#> 1 2013         NA
#> 2 2015          2
#> 3 2017          0
#> 4 2025          8
#> 5 2050         25
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>